# Flattening a nested json[b] array in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have `jsonb` column `feeds` with data in the form of this:

```
[{
  "id": 99999999,
  "lang": "pt",
  "entities": {
    "urls": [],
    "media": [{
      "id": 123456456,
      "type": "photo",
      "id_str": "123456456",
      "indices": [37, 59],
    }]
  },
  "favorited": false,
  "retweeted": false,
  "truncated": false
}]
```

How do I query the **first** `media ->> id` since it's in an json array? So that the result is like this:

```
   id             media_id
---------------------------
99999999         123456456
```

I tried `jsonb_array_elements` but can't seem to get the output I want, especially the part where the `media` is nested within another array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out

```
SELECT
  jsonb_array_elements(feeds)->>'id',
  (((jsonb_array_elements(feeds)->'entities')->'media')->0)->>'id' as media
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select feeds::jsonb->0->>'entities'->>'media'->0->>'id' from table;
```